# Prevent AngularJS modal from closing based on logic inside the modal controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-bootstrap

Is there a way to prevent the an AngularJS modal from closing/dismissing in the controller logic of the modal?

What I want is to show a warning when the users closes the modal and the form inside the modal contains unsaved data.

I've tried searching for a before close event or something else I could use in the [official documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal), but no luck so far.

Comment: In the docs they're using a cancel function upon clicking on the cancel button. Which then calls "$modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');" inside the ModalInstanceCtrl. Can't you just check in there if there's any unsaved data?

Comment: Unfortunately the modal also closes when the user clicks on the backdrop or presses the escape key, this functionality should be left unchanged.

Comment: I checked the source code for the modal directive and I can't find anything that allow you to prevent it from closing. Either fork it and modify the module or use something else. You could suggest this feat to the angular-ui team, maybe even add it yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can watch the 'modal.closing' event, broadcasted to the modal's scope, like this:

```
.controller('modalCtrl', function($scope, $modalInstance) {

  $scope.$on('modal.closing', function(event, reason, closed) {
      var r = prompt("Are you sure you wanna close the modal? (Enter 'YES' to close)");

      if (r !== 'YES') {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
  });
})
```

The first parameter is the *event*, which you can *preventDefault()* to prevent it from closing.

The second parameter is the reason (whatever is passed to the *$close()* method)

The third parameter is a *boolean* indicating whether the modal was closed or dismissed.

Here a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/elkdUxl73ZGKvjqwlrwR?p=preview)

I don't know when this was added, but currently it is mentioned in the official documentation.

Answer (score 2):

If you set `backdrop: 'static'` in your `modalInstance`, solve the problem?

Like this:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  ...
  backdrop: 'static',
  ...
});
```

Then, you need only control the ngClick button responsible to close the modal.

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE 1 [only more info]**

Use `keyboard: false` for disable `Escape`:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  ...
  backdrop: 'static',
  keyboard: false
  ...
});
```

**UPDATE 2**

I researched and found an option. In your modal controller, use:

```
$modalInstance.result.then(function (e) {
    //...
}, function (e) {
    //called before modal close
});
```

Example:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  templateUrl: templateUrl,
  controller: modalController
});

function modalController($scope, $modalInstance){

... //your code

  $modalInstance.result.then(function (e) {
      //...
  }, function (e) {
      //called before modal close
  });

... //your code

}
```

But you need a way to not continue the events for to close the modal. Or allow user save the data before close modal. That's what got so far.

**UPDATE 3**

[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617610/angular-ui-bootstrap-modal).

Comment: Thanks for thinking along, I also thought of this but the product owner wants the dialog to be dismissable when selecting the backdrop. So making it static is not an option unfortunately

Comment: Thanks a lot! Am I correct that the last update specifies how to catch the event, but not a way to prevent it from preceding?

Comment: I believe there is no way to prevent the closing of the modal, in the way I understand what you want. You may attempt to override the methods of the modal. Any news I have, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This will stop the backdrop from triggering a $modal.close event:

```
$modal.open({
   // ... other options
   backdrop  : 'static',
   keyboard  : false
});
```

The keyboard's `ESC` key can still close the modal, so if you want to diable that use `keyboard: false`